# My desktop wallpaper screen becomes fuzzy and pixelated after turning on

Tags: desktop-background, visual-artifacts

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my DELL G3 (now upgraded to 20.04.2). Everything worked fine, but after installing my graphics card driver (460) the background became fuzzy (Nvidia 1650Ti). I downloaded the driver through Additional Drivers. It was using Nouveau before.

[image: desktop screenshot with wavy multicoloured wallpaper and yellow squares]

Laptop Specifications:

- Dell G 3 (2019)
- NVIDIA   (1650 Ti) 460 driver
- Ubuntu (20.04.2)

After turning on I have to change the wallpaper to remove those fuzzy things.

I have tried using wallpaper with less / more memory but there was no change.

Also tried changing resolution, but no change.

Sometimes even font appear distorted in the same way.

Please suggest proper solutions.

Wallpaper without distortion (after changing wallper to default):

[image: normal looking default Ubuntu wallpaper]

Wallpaper after restarting laptop:

[image: weird artifacts on wallpaper]

Comment: problem solved -i updated to 21.04

Comment: yes i was having the smae problem